# Exceeding Page Speed API Limits using async. How can i slow it down?

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, google-pagespeed-insights-api

I've created code to call the Page Speed Insights API.

The build_cwv_data is an async coroutine that calls the api and retrieves and processes json data for a particular URL.

According to the documentation the API has a limit of 400 requests per 100 seconds. And interestingly it is at around the 100 second mark that the API starts returning a 409 error status code (quota exceeded)

My code is doing approximately 775 calls in 100 seconds.

I don't understand how it is making so many calls in that time period as I have added sleep delays to try to slow it down.

Firstly, why is it still so fast? What can I do to slow it down?

````
async def retrieve_cwv_data(urls_list):    
    site_id = 10234
    tasks = []
    rate_limit = 2  # maximum number of API calls per second
    interval = 1 / rate_limit  # interval between API calls in seconds
    count = 0
    start_time = time.monotonic()  # initial start time

    for url in urls_list:
        task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(build_cwv_data(site_id, url, 'mobile', psi_key))
        task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(build_cwv_data(site_id, url, 'desktop', psi_key))
        tasks.append(task1)
        tasks.append(task2)
        count += 2
        if count >= rate_limit * 2:
            elapsed_time = time.monotonic() - start_time
            if elapsed_time < interval:
                # introduce delay to stay within the rate limit
                await asyncio.sleep(interval - elapsed_time)
            # reset count and start time for the next second
            count = 0
            start_time = time.monotonic()

    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    tmp_list = []
    for result in results:
        tmp_list.append(result)
    return tmp_list```
````

Comment: You can use asyncio primitives to achieve this - see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made the pause while *creating* the tasks - but they only start to get executed when you pass the control from your code to the asyncio loop, in the call to `asyncio.gather`: at that point all your taks are actually executed as fast as possible (each next task starts as soon as the previous one, internally, sends a request and awaits for its response). In other words: you are making the calls as fast as your computer can go - the delay that makes the fault happen around the 100th second is because you have delays *before* the tasks actually start to making requests.

Always keep in mind that asyncio code is just regular, serialized code, running in a single thread with *explicit* pause points: no code out of what you are looking at ever runs unless you reach one of those pause-points (or, of course, delegate something to another thread or process) - and the pause points are either the `await` keyword, or `async for` and `async with`.

You have to change your code so that it can work - one way to do that is a semaphore, that could hold the limit of concurrent ongoing requests to 400 and then add some pause.

```
from asyncio import Semaphore
from time import time

call_semaphore = None
timeout = 100

...


async def makecall(*args):
    async with call_semaphore:
        start = time()
        await build_cwv_data(*args)
        elapsed = time() - start
        # ensure the semaphore slot usage for this task is just fred observing the rate limit:
        await time.sleep(max(0, timeout - elapsed))
        


async def retrieve_cwv_data(urls_list):    
    global call_semaphore
    call_semaphore = Semaphore(400)
    site_id = 10234
    tasks = []


    for url in urls_list:
        task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(makecall(site_id, url, 'mobile', psi_key))
        task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(makecall(site_id, url, 'desktop', psi_key))
        tasks.append(task1)
        tasks.append(task2)

    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    tmp_list = []
    for result in results:
        tmp_list.append(result)
    return tmp_list
```

Comment: thanks for your response, when i try your code im getting the following error to do with the call_semaphore context manager:
"with call_semaphore: AttributeError: __enter__" do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: My  bad - it should be `async with call_semaphore: ` not just `with call_semaphore: ` - I am changing it above.